# Extentending a class in decorator breaks static property inheritance

Tags: typescript, decorator, prototypal-inheritance

[Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/4xl6v3xj17) with failing test in file **weird.spec.ts** (Ignore the React stuff).
To see the failing test click on *Show tests* in the top-right-corner.
[image: Show Tests icon]

I have a class and a decorator that I use for validation:

```
function Validate(original: any) {
    return (class extends original {
            constructor(...args: any[]) {
                super(...args);
                // some validation here,
                // throwing a custom error
            }
        }
    ) as any;
}

@Validate
export class Weird {
    public value: string;

    constructor(value: string) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    static thing = new Weird('thing');
}
```

My problem (as can be seen in the failing test) is that

```
Weird.thing instanceof Weird // false
```

I have also tried using a getter for this, and it works as expected, but that would return a new instance every time. What I really want is:

1. Static property to allow using the class as in an "enum" way
2. Returns same instance (initialised once)
3. Maintains inheritance.
4. Is not an explicitly-coded-by-hand "cached static getter". I'm fine with the compiler doing this for me.

What would I need to tweak to change the current behaviour to match what I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a [known issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/9868) that static initializers run before the decorator is applied and hence see the undecorated class.  As a workaround, you can set `Weird.thing` after the class definition:

```
@Validate
class Weird {
    public value: string;

    constructor(value: string) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    static thing: Weird;
}
Weird.thing = new Weird('thing');
```

Comment: It looks like if I add it using `Weird.thing = new Weird('thing')` I get a TS error, and even if I ignore it, I still don't get auto-completion in IDEA for `thing` when I type in `Weird.th`.

Comment: It works for me.  What is the full error you get?  (Note, I just added a missing type annotation on `thing`, but I don't think that could have been the problem.)

Comment: `Error:(29, 19) TS2339: Property 'thing' does not exist on type 'typeof Weird'.`

Comment: Nevermind, I had not declared it before initializing :)